# PHP temp_name and move_uploaded_file error

Tags: php, file, upload

I am using following code to upload my files:

```
<?php include("./phpincludes/header.inc.php");

    $status = "";

    if(@$_POST['submit']){

        $pic = @$_FILES['pic']['name'];
        $pic_temp = @$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];
        $pic_type = @$_FILES['pic']['type'];
        $pic_size = @$_FILES['pic']['size'];

        $doc1 = @$_FILES['doc1']['name'];
        $doc1_temp = @$_FILES['doc1']['tmp_name'];
        $doc1_type = @$_FILES['doc1']['type'];
        $doc1_size = @$_FILES['doc1']['size'];

        $doc2 = @$_FILES['doc2']['name'];
        $doc2_temp = @$_FILES['doc2']['tmp_name'];
        $doc2_type = @$_FILES['doc2']['type'];
        $doc2_size = @$_FILES['doc2']['size'];

        $name = stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['name'])));
        $phone1 = stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['phone1'])));
        $phone2 = stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['phone2'])));
        $address = stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['address'])));
        $sec = stripcslashes(htmlspecialchars(urldecode($_POST['sec_amount'])));

        if($name != ""){


            if($pic_size <= 1048576){
                if (!$pic_temp) { // if file not chosen
                   echo "ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button. ".$pic_temp;
                }
                $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvrstwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZ0123456789";
                $rand_dir_name = $name." ".substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);

                mkdir("uploads/vendors/$rand_dir_name");
                move_uploaded_file($doc1_temp, "uploads/vendors/$rand_dir_name/$doc1");
                move_uploaded_file($doc2_temp, "uploads/vendors/$rand_dir_name/$doc2");
                if(move_uploaded_file($pic_temp, "uploads/vendors/$rand_dir_name/$pic")){
                    echo "uploads/vendors/$rand_dir_name/$pic";
                } else {
                    echo "move_uploaded_file function failed";
                }

            }else{
                echo "Image size should be less than 1 MB!";
            }

        }else{
            echo "Name is neccassary!";
        }


    }

?>
```

but the problem is that it gives me error while uploading the file  'ERROR: Please browse for a file before clicking the upload button.' and 'move_uploaded_file function failed'. i think that problem is with that @ in front of files but when i remove it gives me error of undefined index.

My HTML form:-

```
<form method='POST' name='form'>
                <td><h4>Photo:</h4><input type='file' name='pic' accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png"><h4>Full Name:</h4><input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name'></td>
                <td><h4>Phone 1:</h4><input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Phone' name='phone1'>
                <h4>Phone 2:</h4><input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Phone' name='phone2'></td>
                <td>
                    <h4>Document 1:</h4>
                    <input type='file' name='doc1'>

                    <h4>Document 2:</h4>
                    <input type='file' name='doc2'>
                </td>
                <td><h4>Service:</h4><input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Service' name='services'>
                <h4>Address:</h4><input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Address' name='address'></td>
                <td> <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Sercurity Amount' name='sec_amount'></td>
                <td >
                    <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' style='display:none;'/>
                    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign tableglyp blue' aria-hidden='true' onclick='submit()'>
                    </i>
                </td>
                </form>
```

Please help !

Comment: @ suppress the error/warnings from the view. seems like `$_FILES` values could be unset in some case. so please check whether you get `$_FILES` value. by using `var_dump` or `print_r`

Comment: Let's see your form HTML

Comment: @Rasclatt See my html form in my post

Comment: Your form tag needs to have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to send files

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for your errors are:

1) The html on your form won't pass files because form tag is missing attribute

2) Your logic for checking the status of things is flawed.

3) You are doing your processing very manually

4) Use the `@` symbol sparingly *(as in almost never)*, you want to fix errors

Here is a very basic upload script to take a look at. To start off, I like to organize the `$_FILES` array first, it makes it more readable for me. Lastly, make all the business logic into functions so you can get their logic off the page (you would include them when you want to use them):

**/functions/getFiles.php**

```
function getFiles()
    {
        $files  =   array();
        foreach($_FILES as $keyname => $files) {
            foreach($_FILES[$keyname]['name'] as $key => $value) {
                if($_FILES[$keyname]['error'][$key] != 0)
                    continue;

                $file[$keyname][$key]['name']       =   $_FILES[$keyname]['name'][$key];
                $file[$keyname][$key]['type']       =   $_FILES[$keyname]['type'][$key];
                $file[$keyname][$key]['tmp_name']   =   $_FILES[$keyname]['tmp_name'][$key];
                $file[$keyname][$key]['error']      =   $_FILES[$keyname]['error'][$key];
                $file[$keyname][$key]['size']       =   $_FILES[$keyname]['size'][$key];
            }
        }

        return $file;
    }
```

This function will turn the `$_FILES` array from:

```
Array
(
    [pic] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => IMG_7506.JPG.jpeg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /datatmp/phpTNMUP2
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1003150
                )

        )

    [doc] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => gI_0_DiscoveryLogovertical1.jpg
                    [1] => gI_0_DiscoveryLogovertical2.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /datatmp/phpjY1IYG
                    [1] => /datatmp/phpVsX37k
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 43318
                    [1] => 43318
                )

        )

)
```

to:

```
Array
(
    [pic] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => IMG_7506.JPG.jpeg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /datatmp/phpTNMUP2
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 1003150
                )

        )

    [doc] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => gI_0_DiscoveryLogovertical1.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /datatmp/phpjY1IYG
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 43318
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => gI_0_DiscoveryLogovertical2.jpg
                    [type] => image/jpeg
                    [tmp_name] => /datatmp/phpVsX37k
                    [error] => 0
                    [size] => 43318
                )

        )

)
```

Now you create a function that does the uploading. Here is a simple example:

**/functions/uploadFiles.php**

```
function uploadFiles($files,$dir,&$errors,$max = 1048576)
    {
        if(!is_dir($dir)) {
            if(!mkdir($dir,0755,true))
                throw new Exception('Upload folder could not be created.');
        }

        foreach($files as $key => $file) {
            $name   =   preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\.\-\_]/','',$file['name']);
            if(empty($name)) {
                $error[$key][]  =   'Name can not be empty.';
                continue;
            }

            if($file['size'] > $max) {
                $errors[$key][] =   htmlspecialchars($file['name']).' is too large ('.number_format($max/1024,0).' KB max)';
                continue;
            }

            if(!move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],$dir.$file['name']))
                $errors[$key][] =   'File could not be uploaded';
        }
    }
```

It's easier to have this as a re-usable function:

**/functions/createRandName.php**

```
function createRandName($name)
    {
        $chars  =   "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvrstwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXWZ0123456789";
        return $name." ".substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    }
```

To use:

```
# Include the functions here
require_once(__DIR__.'/functions/createRandName.php');
# ...etc.

# Set your error array
$errors =   array();

#check that a post is set
if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    # Create the directory
    $dir    =   __DIR__.'/'.createRandName(preg_replace('/[^0-9a-zA-Z\s\_\-]/','',$_POST['name'])).'/';
    # Because the upload hinges on a folder being created first that doesn't
    # already exist, we want to stop the process as a whole if the directory
    # fails to be created
    try {
        # Organize the files and loop through them
        foreach(getFiles() as $input => $files) {
            # Upload the files
            uploadFiles($files,$dir,$errors);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        $errors[]   =   $e->getMessage();
    }
}
# Report errors
if(!empty($errors))
    print_r($errors);
?>
```

Your form tag needs `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to upload files. You should array all your file names so `pic[]` and `doc[]`, even when you only have one file. That way your files can all use the same upload mechanism above.

```
<table>
    <form method='POST' name='form' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <td>
            <h4>Photo:</h4>
            <input type='file' name='pic[]' accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png">
            <h4>Full Name:</h4>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Name' name='name'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>Phone 1:</h4>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Phone' name='phone[1]'>
            <h4>Phone 2:</h4>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Phone' name='phone[2]'></td>
        <td>
            <h4>Document 1:</h4>
            <input type='file' name='doc[]'>

            <h4>Document 2:</h4>
            <input type='file' name='doc[]'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h4>Service:</h4>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Service' name='services'>
            <h4>Address:</h4>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Address' name='address'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='tableinput' type='text' placeholder='Sercurity Amount' name='sec_amount'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' />
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign tableglyp blue' aria-hidden='true' onclick='submit()'></i>
        </td>
    </form>
</table>
```

Using this form layout, your form post array would look like this:

```
Array
(
    [name] => My Name
    [phone] => Array
        (
            [1] => 123-123-1233
            [2] => 321-698-7894
        )

    [services] => Something
    [address] => 123 My Street
    [sec_amount] => 123
    [submit] => Submit
)
```